# Find if field name with JsonParser

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am building a custom deserializer (DelegatingDeserializer) and I need to find the name of the field it is currently deserializing. Here is a sample of my code :

```
@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

    Object result = _delegatee.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

    if(result == null) {
        throw ctxt.mappingException(String.format("Field %s : null" + 
          "value rejected. All fields non optional are required.", ??????));
    }

    return result;
}
```

My problem is that I need to find the name of the field but the result is a simple `null` so I have no idea where I can find this information ?

Comment: You cannot. This information is held at `_delegatee` level and as long as `_delegatee` is not informing you which field is not filled, you will not know it (without modifying `_delegatee`). You can use `Bean Validation API` for this kind of processing.

Comment: In fact I found this name in `((TreeTraversingParser) jp)._nodeCursor._currentName` but obviously that's not the intended usage

Comment: Actually `JsonParser` instance should give access, either via `getCurrentName()`, or through `getParsingContext()`. But you are also right in that use of such name information is discouraged.

Comment: Problem of getCurrentName is that it implies a browse of the JsonParser and since it is already done by the deserializer, I cannot do it anymore, it will return `null`